# How to set anchor tag pseudo-element width to wrap content of anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

I want a bar to appear below an anchor tag (in a paragraph) when I hover over it.

```css
#main-paragraph {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 510px;
}

#main-paragraph a {
    display: inline-block;
    transition: color 500ms;
}

#main-paragraph a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#main-paragraph a::after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 1px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #FF9966, #FF6565);
    border-radius: 0.5px;
    transition: width 500ms;
}

#main-paragraph a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p id="main-paragraph">(some other stuff) ... here's a link to <a>wikipedia</a>.</p>
```

The width of the bar that appears (the `::after` pseudo-element) is equal to the width of the paragraph (510 px), rather than the width of the content of the anchor tag (wikipedia).

How do I make a bar appear just below the link and not have it fill the entire width of the paragraph that the link is in? By the way, setting the width of the paragraph is necessary for me.

Comment: make your anchor `position:relative` - the absolute positioned elements are set to the first positioned ancestor

Comment: @Pete Thanks. It solved my problem.